# Image upload from canvas

Tags: ajax, html, spring-mvc, backbone.js

Some one please help me, This is the first time i am using canvas in html,and the question is, is there any way to pass the image from canvas into server using multipart file upload in form submission ....

Answer (score 1):

yes you can upload your canvas with  canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg') and ajax

```
$.post('/upload',
{
    uid : uid,
    img : canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg')
},
function(data) {});
```

for multi-part upload visit this question

[JavaScript Blob Upload with FormData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18253378/javascript-blob-upload-with-formdata)

and its easy way for convert canvas to blob

https://blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob/test/